# Type parameter to ensure relational operators

Tags: scala, generics, types

I have been trying to determine how one might write a type parameter that restricts a function to types that support relational operators?

For example:

```
def biggerOf[A <: ???](a: A, b: A): A = { if (a > b) a else b }
```

Where `???` is my dilemma.  Advanced type parameter bits are new to me, so asking for a little help.  Thought AnyVal might be a winner but for Unit type (and Boolean which won't break, but won't work either).  Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to bring the `Ordering` typeclass into play.

```
import scala.math.Ordering.Implicits.infixOrderingOps

def biggerOf[A:Ordering](a: A, b: A): A = { if (a > b) a else b }
```

`A:Ordering` restricts `A` to types in the `Ordering` typeclass and `infixOrderingOps` enables the convenience operators (methods) such as `<`, `>=`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [**ordering**](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/math/Ordering.html) [**typeclass**](https://tpolecat.github.io/2013/10/12/typeclass.html).

```
def biggerOf[A : Ordering](a: A, b: A): A = {
  import Ordering.Implicits._
  if (a > b) a else b
}
```

Comment: Super cool - jwvh beat you to the answer by just a bit.  I prefer your import style here, but the explicit import does make the answer a bit more clear.  Good looking out!  Thank you.

Comment: @reverend importing implicits by their specific name is usually referred to as a bad practice since the authors are free to always change it and you never refer to them by their name.

Comment: \ Miguel\ Mejía\ Suárez - valid point.  I was just trying to say that seeing `scala.math.Ordering.Implicits.infixOrderingOps` made it very clear to me the underlying "what" that makes these solutions work is all.

Answer (score 0):

As Luis and jwvh has suggested, you can use the `Ordering` typeclass but I'd like to introduce to you the typeclass pattern and using typeclasses in restricting the usage of a function in a more depth.

A typeclass allows one to be able to be flexible in its generic types whilst restricting it enough that those that do not have an instance of the typeclass may not be able to use your function.

Take this as an example, assuming that the Numerical datatypes in Scala have no operators on them, we can generalize the idea of operating on them by introducing the `Num` typeclass and then by specifying their behavior on the operation because these Numerical datatypes have different ways of handling algebraic operations. (e.g an Integral vs Real number)

```scala
trait Num[A] {

  def add(l: A, r: A): A
  def sub(l: A, r: A): A
  def mul(l: A, r: A): A
  def div(l: A, r: A): A

}

object NumTest {
  def addThenMultiply[A](l: A, r: A)(implicit ev: Num[A]): A =
    ev.mul(ev.add(l, r), r)

  //then we create Num instances for numerical types

  implicit val intNum = new Num[Int] { /* implementation*/ }
  implicit val floatNum = new Num[Float] { /* implementation */ }
}
```

Now in this case, the function `addThenMultiply` will only work for `Int` and `Float` datatypes since they're the only ones that have a `Num` instance but you can add instances for other custom datatypes also depending on your need.

Comment: While this is a good answer is somewhat off-topic, it may be better to make Ordering itself, so at least you would solve OP question. Also, my answer links to a similar basic introduction.